# Cannot send email by email class in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I am using codeigniter 4 to create my website. At this moment, I am trying to implement a function which sends email to the users! However, I got this message... Is there any solution to solve it? Here is my code

[This is the error...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWvSg.png)
The error message is "Unable to send email using SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method"

```
$to = "xxx@gmail.com";

        $from = 'xxx@gmail.com';
        $name = 'xxx';
        $subject = "Verification Code";
        $message = "<p> This is your verification code: 123456 </p>";

        $email->setFrom($from, $name);
        $email->setTo($to);
        $email->setSubject($subject);
        $email->setMessage($message);
        if($email->send()){
            echo "Please check your email";
        }else{
            $data = $email->printDebugger(["header"]);
            print_r($data);

        }
```

Comment: [Start here](https://www.google.com/search?q=codeigniter+smtp)

Comment: `$to = xxx@gmail.com;` Really? No quotes at all?

Comment: And please put your error mesage in the question and not the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem already. It's because my server does not permit outgoing traffic to the Internet so I need to use specific host name instead of using my email address!

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have mentioned that you are using "gmail.com" to send your mail. Please note that you have to **unable less secure apps** in the google account to be able to connect SMTP with gmail.

1. Please refer this google documentation for more info on how to do it: [Send email from a printer, scanner, or app](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en#gmail-smpt-option)
2. Please also check this article [Less secure apps & your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en#zippy=%2Cif-less-secure-app-access-is-on-for-your-account%2Cif-less-secure-app-access-is-off-for-your-account)

**Please also ensure that your server firewall does not block port 465 or 587**